# Chrome is unresponsive and glitchy

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, intel-graphics, chromium, 15.10

I've got a pretty performant laptop: a Thinkpad T430 with a top CPU, 16GB RAM (no swap), SSD, Intel 4000 GPU.

In **Google Chrome** (latest stable), I'm suffering from **unresponsive and jerky scrolling**.

I've installed **Kubuntu 15.10** from scratch, and now Chrome also has **redraw problems**: when scrolling or switching tabs, **viewport tears** and displays mixed portions of old and new viewports:

[image: screenshot]

This shit is screenshottable, so it's not a hardware GPU issue.

Neither of these problems happens in other apps.

The intensity of the problem seems to be proportional to the number of open tabs. I've noticed that leaving a YouTube tab open in background has an immediately noticeable effect. With one tab tearing seems to be gone, but scrolling is still very unresponsive.

How do I resolve this issue once and for all?

Comment: Chrome is a 3rd party application so I suggest you file a bug report upstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same. Go to chrome://flags/ and enable "Override software rendering list" flag. This is not a permanent solution. Hope it helps.